# Access Violation Error

Tags: python, scripting

I have a small Blender 2.78c file with one (active) object, one material which is assigned to the object. It uses a UVMap with one images.

Blender crashes at the last line of the script below and the crash report is nothing but

```
Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
```

I have reduced my script so that the error and crash still appear, but the code does not make sense anymore. Any hints on why this happens would be highly appreciated.

```
object = bpy.context.scene.objects.active
uv = object.data.uv_textures[0].data  
for slot in object.material_slots:
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
    bpy.ops.object.material_slot_assign()
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')

uv[1].image
```

Please find the file under:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/poirg3qf70a5c7y/Testfile.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that there is something around this reason:

- You take an internal pointer *"uv = object.data.uv_textures[0].data"*
- This pointer is modified/reallocated during *"bpy.ops.object.material_slot_assign()"*
- So *"uv[x]"* is no longer available

You can instead do something like that:

```
import bpy

object = bpy.context.scene.objects.active

uv = object.data.uv_textures[0].data  

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')

for i, slot in enumerate( object.material_slots ):
    for p in [p for p in object.data.polygons if p.select]:
        p.material_index = i
    #bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
    #bpy.ops.object.material_slot_assign()
    #bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')

print( uv[1].image )
```

Or, of course, access to an available pointer again:

```
import bpy


object = bpy.context.scene.objects.active

uv = object.data.uv_textures[0].data  

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')

for i, slot in enumerate( object.material_slots ):
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
    bpy.ops.object.material_slot_assign()
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')

uv = object.data.uv_textures[0].data  
print( uv[1].image )
```

... but I don't get the meaning of this loop, as it will assign to the last material at the end (probably because this is an extract of the whole code...).

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Additionally, you gave me that most helpful hint with `polygon.material_index`. My script does work now. Thank You.